# corrupted link - send email - exchange server - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, email, character-encoding, exchange-server, phpmailer

I need to send a link within HTML email using CodeIgniter.

- first trial:-

  send an email to using Gmail server, then the link will be sent successfully without any corruption.
- Second trial:

I am using Microsoft Exchange Server.
when sending the link within the HTML email, the link will be received corruptly!!

I don't know why? Then the problem occurred when using only Exchange server.

correct link

> http://000.00.0.00/s/admin/r?i=7&e=hana@dom.edu.com

corrupted link

> http://000.00.0.00/s/admin/r?i=7&e=hana@do=.edu.com

If I put it within **a href tag**

correct link

> http://000.00.0.00/s/admin/r?i=7&e=2

corrected link

> > http://000.00.0.00/s/admin/r=i=7&e=2

My IP= 000.00.0.00, it is not the actual but it is just an example

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the crlf setting to use Exchange as an SMTP server.
Add `$this->email->set_crlf( "\r\n" );`to your controller or add `$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";` to your email config file!

The equal signs getting substituted into your email message are a dead giveaway that the end of line character is the issue.